# Video Size/Duration Limitation that can be uploaded on S3 through Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

A newbie question but I have googled a bit and can't seem to find any solution.

Is there any max **VIDEO** size or duration limit by AWS, that can be uploaded on S3 cloud storage using APIs in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

Per the AWS S3 documentation:

**Upload objects in a single operation:**

> With a single PUT operation, you can upload objects up to 5 GB in
>   size. For more information, see Uploading Objects in a Single
>   Operation. Upload objects in parts—Using the multipart upload API, you
>   can upload large objects, up to 5 TB.

**The multipart upload API**

> is designed to improve the upload experience for larger objects. You
>   can upload objects in parts. These object parts can be uploaded
>   independently, in any order, and in parallel. You can use a multipart
>   upload for objects from 5 MB to 5 TB in size.

So it depends on whether or not you're using a multipart form or not, but you only can only do 5GB in a single PUT operation.